# Appending arbitrary code to a pgfplots axis environment before curve and axes are drawn

Tags: pgfplots

*There was some confusion about what I really wanted, so I include the actual use case here. The MWE plus corresponding picture is at the bottom of the post.*

I made some fancy looking graph, among which use custom grid lines. Some of the grid lines don't go all the way to my custom defined axis. What's my best shot at getting it done?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kIU9gjT.png]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes, positioning}
\tikzset{
  shadowed/.style={preaction={
      transform canvas={shift={(2pt,-1pt)}},draw opacity=.2,#1,preaction={
        transform canvas={shift={(4pt,-1.75pt)}},draw opacity=.1,#1,preaction={
          transform canvas={shift={(6pt,-2.5pt)}},draw opacity=.05,#1,preaction={
          transform canvas={shift={(8pt,-3.25pt)}},draw opacity=.025,#1,
        }
        }}}},
}
\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotsdataxmin{\pgfplots@data@xmin}
\def\pgfplotsdataxmax{\pgfplots@data@xmax}
\def\pgfplotsdataymin{\pgfplots@data@ymin}
\def\pgfplotsdataymax{\pgfplots@data@ymax}
\makeatother
\pgfplotsset{
    range frame/.style={
        tick align=outside,
        axis line style={opacity=0},
        after end axis/.code={
            \draw[cyan,thick,double=white,double distance=1.4pt,line cap=round,rounded corners] ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}-|{axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmin,0}) --   ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:0,\pgfplotsdataymin}) -- ({rel axis cs:-.1,0}|-{axis cs:0,\pgfplotsdataymax});
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[range frame,
        domain=25.29325198:97,
        axis lines*=left,
        yticklabel=\empty,
        xticklabels=\empty,
        xtick style={draw=none},
        ytick style={draw=none},
extra description/.code={%
\node[] at (axis cs:6,60) {$60$};
\node[] at (axis cs:8.6,40) {$40$};
\node[] at (axis cs:11.5,20) {$20$};
\node[] at (axis cs:15,0) {$0$};
\node[] at (axis cs:25,-11.3) {$25$};
\node[] at (axis cs:50,-11.3) {$50$};
\node[] at (axis cs:75,-11.3) {$75$};
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:25,-9) -- (axis cs:25,-7);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:50,-9) -- (axis cs:50,-7.5);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:75,-9) -- (axis cs:75,-7.5);
\node[] at (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmin-15.5,\pgfplotsdataymax+4.4) {$m_\mathrm{gr}$};
\node[] at (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax+5.5,\pgfplotsdataymin-7) {$m_\mathrm{f}$};
}
]
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:-8.05,20) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,20);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:-8.05,0) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,0);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:-8.05,40) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,40);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:-8.05,60) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,60);
\addplot[shadowed={double=gray,draw=gray},thick,line cap=round,rounded corners, draw=purple,double=white,double distance=1.6pt,
]  {-23.73194+0.9382716*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatother


\end{document}
```

---

**Original post:** I am forced to produce my own grid lines, but the axes overlap the grid lines when I use the code below. This causes a part of my grid lines to be ignored. I wish to draw them directly behind the axes and obey my specified x-coordinates. How can I draw the lines before the axes and curve are drawn, but without the overlapping white space produced by the axes?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8c8YjMh.png]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
extra description/.code={%preaction={ %preaction doesn't work
},%}
]
\draw[ultra thick,lightgray] (axis cs:-2,2) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,2);
\draw[ultra thick,lightgray] (axis cs:.04,4) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,4);
\draw[ultra thick,lightgray] (axis cs:0,6) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,6);
\addplot[
] table {
dof l2_err level
.2 2.6 2
.4 2.3 4
.5 2.4 5
.6 1.1 6
.7 1.8 7
.8 4.6 8
.9 3.3 9
1 6.2 10
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try move those description code down -- right after the axis option but before the addplot[] table

Comment: Looks like standard grid to me. You can do this via layers or `begin plot visualization` (?! I always confuse these key names). I feel there is more complication than what you have given here.

Comment: @percusse I need the grid to start at a different x position based on the height of the grid line. That's the problem.

Comment: @Jesse Very good suggestion, the problem is that the axes will overlap, causing a part of the grid line not to appear. Your suggestion somes extremely close, though.

Comment: @1010011010-- To fix that tiny overlap, draw the table again by adding `\begin{axis}[ticks=none] 
\addplot[] table {...}; \end{axis}` one more time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `execute at <begin/end> <certain events>` keys for a more consistent output. Also instead of the max data point you can use `axis description cs` to get the whole axis length independent from where the data points are.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
my extras/.style={
  execute at begin axis={
    \draw[ultra thick,lightgray] (axis cs:.08,2) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,2);
    \draw[ultra thick,lightgray] (axis cs:.04,4) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,4);
    \draw[ultra thick,lightgray] (axis cs:0,6) -- (axis cs:\pgfplots@data@xmax,6);
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[my extras]
\addplot+[ultra thick,
] table {
dof l2_err level
.2 2.6 2
.4 2.3 4
.5 2.4 5
.6 1.1 6
.7 1.8 7
.8 4.6 8
.9 3.3 9
1 6.2 10
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using this solution, later on the axis environment still overwrites the grid lines `:-(`

Comment: @1010011010 I don't know exactly what you mean but look at the `set layers` option in the pgfplots manual. So you can push this to lower levels.

Comment: I've updated my question with the issue at hand. Maybe it'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the updated question seems to be adding

```
clip=false,
```

to the `axis` environment. In your version, the manual horizontal grid lines are clipped outside the original size of the axis.

You should then also adjust the end of the horizontal lines, e.g.:

```
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:17,0) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,0);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:14.3,20) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,20);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:11.6,40) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,40);
\draw[ultra thin,lightgray] (axis cs:9,60) -- (axis cs:\pgfplotsdataxmax,60);
```

For better visibility I changed the line width to `thin` in this preview:
[image: Preview]